# jpql order by subquery produces unexpected AST node exception

Tags: hibernate, playframework, jpql

I translated a working (postgre)sql query to jpql, but hibernate throws a

> org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException:
>   unexpected AST node
>   exception

These are my core model classes:

```
@Entity
public class Piece {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    public AUser user;
    public long index;
...
}

@Entity
public class Vote {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    public AUser receiver;
...
}

@Entity
public class AUser {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="receiver", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<Vote> receivedVotes;
...
}
```

Here is my jpql query:

```
String query = "select p from Piece p order by (select count(v.receiver) from Vote v where v.receiver.id=p.user.id) desc, p.index";
```

Can anyone explain the exception, why it happens and how to change the query to avoid it. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JPQL doesn't support subqueries in `order by`. If I correctly understand your query, you can try something like this:

```
select p 
from Piece p left join p.user.receivedVotes rv
group by p
order by count(rv) desc, p.index
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, your suggestion worked great with a slight adjustment: i had to add "p.id, p.user.id, p.index" to the group by clause