# JPA 2.0 subselect / subquery in order by clause with criteria api

Tags: hibernate, subquery, sql-order-by, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

I want to use JPA 2.0 criteria api to build the order by clause with a subselect. I know that you can do that in plain SQL but can it be mapped with criteria api? Can someone please give a code example?

Example:

```
Order(name, address) // table1

OrderPriority(address, priority) // table2 priority by address

select o from Order o order by (select p.priority from OrderPriority p where 
p.address = o.address)
```

Answer (score 1):

Criteria API queries are converted to JPQL and apparently subqueries in the `order by` clause are not supported in JPQL.

Similar StackOverflow answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5551571/329589).