# JPA limit subquery result (Jhipster)

Tags: java, jpa, jhipster

I need to put

```
order by tabB.id desc
limit 1
```

in a subquery because the subquery must return a single value.

```
        Long filter= Long.parseLong(value);
        return (root, query, builder) -> {
            Subquery<B> subquery = query.subquery(B.class);
            Root<B> subqueryRoot = subquery.from(B.class);
            Join<B,C> ss = subqueryRoot.join(B_.idC);
            subquery.correlate(ss);
            subquery.select(subqueryRoot.get(B_.ID_C));
            subquery.where(
                    builder.equal(subqueryRoot.get(B_.idA),root.get(A_.id))
                    );
            subquery.
            builder.max(subqueryRoot.get(B_.id)); //first try
            builder.desc(subqueryRoot.get(B_.id)); //another try
            return builder.equal(subquery, filter);
        };
```

adding "first try" and/or "another try" nothing changes in the query created, they are simply ignored and executing it I reach:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

Is there a way to take the first element in the subquery so can apply to the where query?

My situation is similar [What are the alternatives to using an ORDER BY in a Subquery in the JPA Criteria API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41240928/what-are-the-alternatives-to-using-an-order-by-in-a-subquery-in-the-jpa-criteria)

but I have a equals not over the id:

```
SELECT q.id_project FROM status q
WHERE q.status_name like 'new'
AND q.id IN (
   SELECT TOP 1 sq.id from status sq
   WHERE q.id_project = sq.id_project 
   ORDER BY sq.id DESC )
```

my situation is:

```
SELECT A.id_project FROM tabA A
WHERE A.col like 'alpha'
AND 'centauri' = (
   SELECT TOP 1 B.colAA from tabB B
   WHERE A.id_project = B.id_project 
   ORDER BY B.id DESC )
```

Comment: SubQuery, maybe `select(Integer size)` or `limit(Integer size)`.

Comment: subquery doens't have these 2 methods.

Comment: One option is to use a subquery of subquery, but It's not beautiful. Are there any other way?